# Fast rectifier diodes in parallel at SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, rectifier, parallel

I'm trying to build a 35 V @ 10 A SMPS.

I don't have 15A diode to rectify the transformer output. Can I use two [BYW29](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/BYW29-D.PDF) in parallel? They are rated at 8A.

I know that when diodes are in parallel, the current doesn't flow equally through them. This means that one will do most of the job and get hot, while the other will be used only when the current reaches 10A?

[Here](http://danyk.cz/iz350_en.html) is the SMPS schematic (I'm going to modify the output to be 35V at 10A instead of -35..0..35 V at 5A). Also I'm going to use two [FS7KM-18A](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/powerex/FS7KM-18A.pdf) MOSFETs in parallel instead of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two devices placed in parallel, regardless of whether they are rectifiers, transistors, resistors, etc. *in any configuration, even with different devices* will operate with the same voltage. In the case of two rectifiers, the total current passed will be distributed across the rectifiers according to their V-I curves such that both have the same forward voltage.

With two similar rectifiers this means that they will have approximately the same current, but with, say, a 1N4007 and a HER307, with a current of 1A the former will pass 800mA and the latter 200mA, with a V<sub>f</sub> of approximately 0.9V.

Comment: So if I'm using two identical diodes there shoudn't be any problem?

Comment: The current will be distributed almost equally, depending on how precise the manufacturing process is.

Comment: What about thermal runaway?

Comment: @jippie: Good point. That completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 3):

Beware of [thermal runaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_runaway#Electrical_engineering)

When two diodes aren't exactly equal (which is the case with actual diodes you buy in a shop), the current through the branches will slightly vary. Due to  this difference in current, the diode with highest current will start warming up slightly, resulting in a slightly better conductivity. The current further increases with respect to the parallel diode and warms up even further. After a little while the current through one of the diodes may be substantially larger than the current through the other diode, possibly stressed beyond its specifications.

You can reduce this effect by using a tight thermal coupling between the diodes, but it is better practice to use either a diode that is spec'd for the total current or add a small series resistor to each of the diodes to improve currents shared equally amongst them.

Comment: This can be seen in figure 1 of the datasheet, which shows reduced resistance (V/I) at higher temperatures.